# Capturing user input as a string in Discord.py rewrite and returning said input in a message

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to capture a users input, what they say in a message, and have it returned to them in a message from the bot. More specifically, when they run a command, it'll return what ever text they have entered after that.

So far, I'm here:

```
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content.startswith["=ok"]:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, message.content[6:])
```

...unfortunately, I believe this was valid for the previous version of Discord.py before the rewrite. Essentially I want someone to be able to run the command =pressf and have the bot return the message "Everyone, lets pay respects to (string)!" An event probably isn't the best way to go about this but I'm stumped.

I've been struggling to find a specific answer online for my issue so I greatly appreciate anyone who could point me in the proper direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) instead of `on_message` event. Here is a simple command:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('A Simple Command')
```

`ctx` parameter is the parameter that all commands must have. So, when you type `=test`, it will send to that channel `A Simple Command`.

If we come to what you try to do, you can use more parameters than `ctx`. Here is how you can do it:

```py
@client.command()
async def pressf(ctx, *, mess):
    await ctx.send(mess)
```

In this code, you have 1 more parameter called `mess` and also there's a `*`. That means `mess` parameter includes every message after `=pressf`. So when a user type `=pressf Hello`, it will send the channel `Hello`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the newer [Commands Extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html), it is much simpler to implement what you are wanting.  See [this bit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) specifically for passing everything a user types after the command into a variable.

There is an official example I would recommend looking at here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py

Comment: Thank you! I’ll take a look at this in the morning.